# DBFlow versus GreenDao orm library in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I am to pick a DAO library for an app that stores lot of data in SQLite tables with relations.

I first choose GreenDao, Since it is being used in many famous apps actively and is quite old, well tested and with bug fixed.

Where as DBFlow uses Annotation processing(Annotations are resolved at compile time, so compilation time will increase) And allows the user to decide the model cache, Sometimes proves faster than GreenDao(In some case only).

But DBFlow might not be having some bugs left or some scenarios uncovered since it is not being used actively in numerous apps like GreenDao is being used. (Sorry! I'm getting a bit Hypothetical).

"Which one is better from performance to code handling, DB migration and model alteration in future".

Have a look first:
[GreenDao performance](http://greendao-orm.com/2015/09/09/android-orm-performance-in-2015/)

[DBFlow comparision with DBFLow](https://github.com/Raizlabs/AndroidDatabaseLibraryComparison)

Guide me. Please.

Comment: What makes you think GreenDao is using reflection on the Android side?

Comment: @tcarvin Yes! Green dao is using optimized code instead of reflection.

Comment: Which one do you suggest me for fast and lasting solution?

Comment: Please add your use case. What features has DBFlow or GreenDao that you need and that one of those libs can not deliver? How big is your database, that the performance is a really issue?